# How to make json objects within array in php

Tags: php, json

I want to make `json` as followsin php:

```
{["key1":"value1"],["key2":"value2"]}
```

Can any one help?

Comment: That's not valid JSON

Comment: This doesn't make a whole lot of sense. Shouldn't the brackets be reversed?

Comment: Have you tried [json_encode](http://php.net/json_encode) ?

Answer (score 0):

See the PHP manual for `json_encode()` and `json_decode()`:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php
http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this: set it to true, if you want an associative array.

```
$array = json_decode('[{"var1":"9","var2":"16","var3":"16"},{"var1":"8","var2":"15","var3":"15"}]',true);
```

if you want to iterate:

```
foreach($array as $item) { //foreach element in $arr
    $uses = $item['var1']; //etc
}
```